# Java compilation issue in loop

Tags: ant

I was trying to perform java compilation using ant 1.8.1. Due to the requirement, I have to compile number of java source folders (containing java files) in a loop. These folder names will be derived from the java project mentioned in the property file. From the loop itself I need to perform java compilation. So I used a macrodef where I am passing all the required parameters for java source compilation. Essentially, I have a main build.xml file from where I am calling build_Compile.xml (responsibility of this is to figure out which Java projects to build and their corresponding source folders and perform compilation in loop for each project). To achieve this I use a macrodef defined in a helper file (Helper.xml) file which contains number of macrodef.

However, when I execute the task, I am getting an error which implies that java src path(being passed as parameter) is not being found properly. What I noticed is the path of the build files (where all my build*.xml files reside) is being appended before the java src directory path(passed as parameter in the macrodef). I printed the parameter being passed to the macrodef which looks as expected. Here is the snippet which I am using for java source compilation -

.....
.....

```
    <javac  srcdir="@{srcpath}" 
            destdir="./Temp/build/classes/" 
            includeAntRuntime="false" 
            classpath="${classpath}" 
            includes="${replacedartefacts}">
    </javac>
```

Sorry for the long story. Appreciate any pointer/guideline. Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: Hi, I have given all details in a new post - "Java compilation issue in loop - Continued". Would be great if you follow that and give me some clue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by *the loop* idea. There are two ways I can think about this:

- You have a single project, but compiling different source directories depending upon the project.
- You have a master *build.xml* that's calling a bunch of sub projects that contain source folders to compile.

In the first example, each `<javac>` call depends upon already compiled classfiles. In the second scenario, each set of Java sources you're compiling is independent of the rest

You don't give the error you're getting or the value of `@{srcdir}` which would help.

I notice you have an `includes` parameter. This is the list of java files to include. I also notice this is a property. That means this cannot be changed once it is set. Why do you have an *includes* parameter? How will specifying a particular set of files to compile for **ALL** project affect what you want to do. Is this some value like `*.java`? Is this something that will be the same for each set of source directories you're compiling?

Could this be an issue with the `${basedir}` property? When you use `<ant>` or `<import>`, your `${basedir}` is set to the calling program's `${basedir}` and not to the `${basedir}` in the called programs.

Run Ant with the `-d` parameter. This will produce hundreds of lines of output, but will show exactly what is going on with each call to `<javac>`. We can give you more help if you also post the exact error message and maybe a bit more information on how your project is setup.

Talking about loops, take a look at the [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) tasks, especially the [for](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) task. Also look into the Ant [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task. The `<for>` task gives you a way to easily loop through a bunch of directory parameters. The `<subant>` task is made for a master build building sub-projects.

Comment: Thanks David. I have provided detail in a new post - "Java compilation issue in loop - Continued". Would be great if you can have a look and provide your comments.